# Creating a temporary file in PHP with a specific name and extension

Tags: php, file, temp

I'm trying to create an attachment that gets sent via email with PHP and PHPMailer. I'm not having trouble doing that, but I specifically need to create a file with a `.ics` extension. I basically want the following to happen:

1. Create a temporary file with a specific name, ie. `My Date.ics`
2. Write a string to that file.
3. Attach the file and send the email.
4. Close the file and delete it (via unlinking it).

Unfortunately, I can't get past step 1. Just doing:

```
$tmpfname = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), 'My Date.ics');
echo $tmpfname;
```

Gives me my file name followed by six random characters. For example the above might say something like this:

```
/tmp/My Date.icsnn8B34
```

I've also gone into `/tmp/` and the files aren't actually  being deleted after they are unlinked via `unlink($tmpfname);`

How can I just get a temporary file with a specific extension?

Comment: do you really need the file. most mailers will take strings as file attachments

Comment: `$tmpFileName = tmpfile() . '.myextension';` ...  try that  (replace `myextension` with whatever you like.  Although this is an XY problem.  You do not actually need to write to a file before sending the mail as [nogad](http://stackoverflow.com/users/6763587/nogad) stated.

Comment: @nogad I completely overlooked that PHPMailer has an `AddStringAttachment` function that lets you create a file from a string file name with a string as the content. Thank you for the help! :)